# after insertion triggers on an auto increment column of another table on Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, insert, auto-increment

I want an after insertion trigger in so i can increase a number which is auto incremented in another table. lets say i have 2 tables  as table1 and table2 , table2 has an int id which is auto incremented. I apply a afterinsertion trigger on table1 so every time the user enter something in the table1, table2's id should auto increment itself and store that number in a variable. 
I tried this but it did not work. Any help would b very appreciated thank u .

[image]

Comment: Note: I am struggling how to write the insert statement inside the trigger.

Comment: You have to specify something in the values clause and if you want table2.id to auto_increment then you cannot specify it in the insert. Does table2 only contain an id and if so whats' the point of this table?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I specified but it still did not work. I forgot to take the recent screenshot.

Comment: Please don't include screen shots - always as text.

Comment: Ok , do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: insert into passport(passport_no) values('robben');     //This is what i inserted in my table inside the trigger but it gives an error which is column count does not match value count at row 1.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your insert so the the error is not coming from where you think. Please add table definitions sample data , the trigger and the insert table1 statement as text to the question.

Comment: Shown query cannot produce shown error message. I think that some another statement is the error source.